# How to un-install Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall

I have 3 partitions. One for Windows 7, one for Ubuntu and one for my files. So, how do I go about un-installing ubuntu? I did not install it using Wubi.

Answer (score 0):

I went through this myself and it was very harrowing to find all the information. It took me almost three hours of continuous testing to finally get it done. It was in February this year. But now I am quite used to it.

This is how I went about in Windows XP and it should work the same in Windows 7 too but I am not sure.

These are the steps for uninstalling any Linux distribution from your computer:

1. Create an Ubuntu USB using Unetbootin or Linux Live USB Creator( as it is required in a subsequent step).
2. Go to windows 7 and in command prompt type `diskmgmt.msc` you will see the partition manager. In there, delete the partition that you created for Linux.
3. Now reboot your machine, You will see the GRUB rescue prompt saying `no partition found`. Don't panic, this is normal. As we have removed the linux partition but did not fix the MBR.
4. Reboot from your USB. I hope you know how to change your BIOS settings so as to boot from a USB. In case you don't, it should be easy to find on the internet as the exact. I cannot tell you the exact steps as the options depend on your motherboard.
5. Once you have booted from the USB, select `try Ubuntu` and wait for the OS to load.
6. Make sure you are connected to the internet and now run a terminal.
7. You need root access, so type:

`sudo passwd root`

type in the password you want

now type:

`su -`

and type in the password at the prompt

now use the following command:

`apt-get install lilo`

and once the installation is complete and the prompt returns then type in:

`lilo -M /dev/sda mbr`

Once done you will get the message in the terminal something like:

`Your Master Boot Record has been fixed`

Once you see this, reboot and you should be able to boot into Windows XP directly.

I don't know if the instructions for Windows 7 are exactly same but hopefully other forum members can help you with the specifics but these are the critical steps. Make sure you have a Ubuntu USB handy as without this I don't think you can fix the MBR.

I have done this a couple of times on my Windows XP machine and it works perfectly fine.

Alternatively if you have a Windows 7 DVD, or rescue disk, you can use that to [restore the original Windows 7 MBR](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html). The steps about will reinstall lilo instead of restoring the original bootloader.

Comment: well it is defnitely not as simple as @Dimitris Theodoridis said. You need to follow the above steps so that you can get it out completely. DOn't follow them and you would be stuck up with the GRUB rescue menu for company!

Answer (score 0):

boot in your windows and open application that is for that stuffs like disk utility in ubuntu (dont know what is name for that in windows) and simply empty that partition, or delete that partition at all if you not need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

its simple, just boot using your bootable usb or any other bootable device

after that delete the partition containing ubuntu..

then start windows7 -> right click my computer -> manage -> disk management --- then u will see unused space --> create a new Drive..

Hope that solves ur problem ..